# A function in C language does not work, what is the cause?

Tags: c

I am a complete beginner in C language.

I want to make a program that three student enter their student ID, name, score then this program print their student ID, name, score, total score and highest score.

I want to also use a subprogram like below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

int best_score(float a, float b);

struct student {
    int number;
    char name[20];
    double grade;
};

int main(){
    struct student list[SIZE];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("enter your student ID : ");
        scanf("%d", &list[i].number);
        printf("enter your name : ");
        scanf("%s", list[i].name);
        printf("enter your score : ");
        scanf("%lf", &list[i].grade);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i< SIZE; i++){
        printf("ID: %d, name: %s, score: %f\n", list[i].number, list[i].name, list[i].grade);
    }

    for(i = 0; i< SIZE; i++){
        float max = best_score(list[i], i);
        float temp = all_score(list[i], i);
    }

    return 0;
}

int best_score(float list[i], int i){
    float max=0;

    if (max < list[i]) {
        max = list[i];
    }

    return max;
}

int all_score(float list[i], int i){
    float temp=0;

    temp += list[i];

    return temp;
}
```

this program's error code is like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3caS.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is `best_score` supposed to take a single score or an array? The definition doesn't match the declaration at the top.

Comment: You're missing a declaration for `all_score`.

Comment: `int best_score(float a, float b);` later `int best_score(float list[i], int i)` and call with `float, int`. What is the number of compiler warnings - do you read them?

Comment: Every time you call `best_score` it initializes `max` to `0`. How do you expect it to compare different scores with each other?

Comment: What do you think "doesn't work"? *How* doesn't it work? What is supposed to happen? What actually happens instead, and how is that different?

Comment: And you have a similar problem with `all_scores`.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

`best_score` and `all_scores` should take an array and do the looping themselves, they shouldn't be called in a loop.

The array should be `struct student`, not `float`, since you don't have an array of just `float`.

The functions should return `float`, not `int`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3

struct student {
    int number;
    char name[20];
    double grade;
};

float best_score(struct student a[], size_t n);
float all_score(struct student a[], size_t n);

int main(){
    struct student list[SIZE];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("enter your student ID : ");
        scanf("%d", &list[i].number);
        printf("enter your name : ");
        scanf("%s", list[i].name);
        printf("enter your score : ");
        scanf("%lf", &list[i].grade);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i< SIZE; i++){
        printf("ID: %d, name: %s, score: %f\n", list[i].number, list[i].name, list[i].grade);
    }

    float max = best_score(list, SIZE);
    float temp = all_score(list, SIZE);
    printf("Best score: %f, All scores: %f\n", max, temp);

    return 0;
}

float best_score(struct student list[], size_t n){
    float max=0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (max < list[i].grade) {
            max = list[i].grade;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

float all_score(struct student list[], size_t n){
    float temp=0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp += list[i].grade;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues:

- score is a `double`, therefore you need to use `double` everytime a score is involved. Right now you're using `int` (like in `int best_score(float a, float b);`), `float` (like in  `float max=0;`) and `double` (like in `double grade;`).
- the declaration `int best_score(float a, float b);` doesn't match the implementation `int best_score(float list[i], int i)`
- The implementation `best_score` cannot work. You need to scan all `SIZE` scores.
- It's unclear what `all_score` is supposed to do (maybe return the sum of all scores?)

You probably want some something like this for `best_score`

```
double best_score(struct student list[])
{
  double max = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    if (max < list[i].grade) {
      max = list[i].grade;
    }
  }

  return max;
}
```

call it like this:

```
double max = best_score(list);
```

Now you should be able to write `all_score` yourself.